# How do I resolve the 'Import openai could not be resolved' error in Visual Studio Code when creating a custom chat GPT bot?

Tags: python, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to make a custom ChatGPT bot in Visual Studio Code and I'm getting the error Import "OpenAI" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) the error code is **reportMissingImports [boolean or string, optional]: Generate or suppress diagnostics for imports that have no corresponding imported python file or type stub file. The default value for this setting is "error".** I'm relatively new to coding so if anyone could give me a nudge in the right direction.

I tried to switch files from a custom file to the download files but that didn't work I also tried opening a terminal and typing `pip3 install openai` but that still didn't work

Comment: _also tried opening a terminal and typing pip3 install openai but that still didn't work_ Okay, so what **did** it do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give us more details and provide a [mre].

Comment: @JohnGordon When I typed pip3 install open ai it gave me the error "pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip3 install openai
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

Comment: Try `pip` instead of `pip3`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I also did that and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Then either you don't have `pip` installed at all, or it's installed somewhere that is not on your PATH variable.